What Algorithm to use for calculating a leaderboard
I would like to use an algorithm for an app where you calculate a leaderboard of people where they have played eachother a different number of times in a match.
For example , for a set week a group of 10 people have a tennis competition where people play eachother randomly a different amount of times and record who beats who.I then want to create a leaderboard from all these scores:
I would like it to take into account :
How ‘difficult’ their opponent was(their win rate)
How many times they played -no bias to people who have played more
And obviously just their score.
Does anyone have suggestions what existing algorithms there are I could work from, or the idea of maths behind it?
Thanks!

Presumably you've looked into industry standard approaches like Elo and TrueSkill? What are your reservations about using one of these off-the-shelf algorithms?
